# Revealing a card in Harry Potter Hogwart's Battle

Tags: harry-potter-hogwarts-battle

A dark arts event and villain abilities will have a player "reveal the top card and if value is X discard and [something else bad happens]".  What happens with the card if the outcome is NOT discarding, ie. the value is less than X?

We have been playing that it goes into the player's hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand, it just goes back on the top of your deck and you'll just know at least one of the cards you get on your next turn.

From [boardgamegeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1650274/reveal-and-discard-if)

> Musketeer84 wrote:
>
> If you don't need to discard a card, would the card sit at the top of the deck or move into your hand for the start of next turn?
>
> The standard interpretation of "reveal" in most deck games is that the card stays in its location, in this case on the top of your deck, unless an instruction says otherwise. The only purpose of a reveal is to make a hidden card public knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for this. But would still hope for an 'official' ruling.  In a way I think adding it to your hand plays better - you get a benefit if you survive, and if there are multiple 'reveals' (eg. event and pettigrew) then there is the chance the next reveal triggers the bad.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find an 'official ruling' on this, but I believe the card goes back on top of your deck.

If the card ONLY said "Reveal the top card." then there would be no debate - you would just look at the top card and return it to the top of the deck. The portion of the rule after the 'and' is a separate instruction.

So think if it this way:
1) Look at and show everyone the top card of your deck and return it.
2) If the top card of your deck has a value of X discard it and [do something]